# Formatting HTML pandas tables in python

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe

I am using Pandas to create 3 HTML tables out of 3 dataframes. The output I want is an HTML file. The code I'm currently using prints tables one under the other. I want to print one table on top, and then the other two tables side by side. What could I change in the code to achieve that?

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(5,4),columns='W X Y Z'.split())
df1 = pd.DataFrame(randn(5,4),columns='A B C D'.split())
df2 = pd.DataFrame(randn(5,4),columns='E F G K'.split())
with open("a.html", 'w') as _file:
    _file.write(df.head().to_html() + "\n\n" + df1.head().to_html()+ "\n\n" + df2.head().to_html())
```

[image: currently my 3 tables look like this, and I want the bottom two to be on the same level, side by side]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my proposal based on your original code:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(5,4),columns='W X Y Z'.split())
df1 = pd.DataFrame(randn(5,4),columns='A B C D'.split())
df2 = pd.DataFrame(randn(5,4),columns='E F G K'.split())

html = """
    {table1}
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>{table2}</td>
        <td>{table3}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    """.format(
        table1=df.head().to_html(),
        table2=df1.head().to_html(),
        table3=df2.head().to_html()
    )
with open("a.html", 'w') as _file:
    _file.write(html)
```